# Mysql Current Timestamp and time() showing different values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

OK. So I have been trying to implement a timer. Now a very weird thing is happening and I can't understand why ?.

Basically I am trying to find the difference between the last access and the current time. I am storing the time of last access in the database. This value is according to the server time. But when I try the time() function of php it shows me values which are 5-6 hours behind the time that I have in the database.

For example: here is my code :

```
    $t1= strtotime($played_row->timer); // Time from the database with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    $t2= strtotime("now"); // Get the current time
```

It shows Year: 2012 Month: 01 Day: 21 - 05:28 pm for t2

and Year: 2012 Month: 01 Day: 21 - 10:28 pm for my timestamp values.

Can anyone tell my why is that ?

P.S:  I am running the code on my computer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is a timezone issue: if you are in the Eastern timezone, you are 5 hours away from UTC right now. If one sytem is returning local time and another is returning UTC this is what you will see.

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't mean that all the software on your computer will report time in the local timezone. UTC is actually quite a standard way of reporting time. Check your PHP and MySQL configuration files.

Comment: Ohk. Got it. Its working now. using date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score 4):

At a guess I would say that your database and PHP are using two different timezone offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone in PHP that is used in your database.

> date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all
>   date/time functions in a script

Alse see [date_default_timezone_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) how to get ini-set timezone.